# The state of art of the sunflower lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-set-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I am interesting in the sunflower system and its applications in computer science.

Given a Universe $U$ and a collection of $k$ sets $A_i$ is called a **k-sunflower system** if $A_i \cap A_j = Y $ for all $i \neq j$. And $Y$ is called as the core and $A_i - Y$ is called petals.

A family of sets $F$ is called $s$-uniform is all the sets it contained possess $s$ elements.

Erdos and Rado proved that for a $s$ uniform family of sets $F$ , $F$ must contain a $k$-sunflower system  petals if $|F| > s!(k-1)^s $.

This result is called the sunflower lemma and has many important applications.

Erdos conjectured that for every $k$ there exist a constant $c_k$ such that the upper bound should be $c_k^s$ every $s$-uniform family $F$.
(The  sunflower conjecture)

Unfortunately, this conjecture is still open for $k=3$.

### Here is what I want to know.

If we limit the number of elements in the universe $U$.Suppose $|U|$= $u$. Then the problem turns out be:

Given a universe with $u$ elements, and $s$-uniform family $F$ of sets containing the elements in $U$, we supposed can find sequence of constants $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ ,... such that every $s$-uniform family $F$ contains a $3$-sunflower system if $|F|>$ $c_i^s$ and $|U|=i$.

Moreover, if we could prove that the sequence $c_i$ converges to a constant $c$, then it seems we can prove the sunflower conjecture.

But I cannot find such result.It might be that this approach is too stupid or too hard.

### Could any one provide the state of art of sunflower lemma and the conjecture(finite version is also OK).

Here is some I can provide. 
There is a chapter in Junka's book The Extremal Combinatorics.

The paper above is one of its application(finite version)

[On Sunflowers and Matrix Multiplication N Alon et.al](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.technion.ac.il%2F~shpilka%2Fpublications%2FASU11.pdf&ei=u_y5UP6rKIWBiQei94DwDg&usg=AFQjCNHnR0rNmULcyDTBGtvG3qsU5a9d2w&sig2=BeclrG8vsTX_DJOAvrwSFg)

Comment: With a finite universe you can take $c_{|U|} > 2^{|U|}$, making the statement vacuous since no $F$ satisfy the condition.

Comment: Nice question. The best result I know is due to Kostochka: For all $m>1$ there is a $c_m$ such that for any $n$, an $n$-uniform family $F$ not admitting a $3$-sunflower system and of largest possible cardinality satisfies $|F|\le c_m n! m^{-n}$. 

Comment: @Andres could you give a link? I have got some Kostochka's papers. ButI might not have this one.

Comment: @Ben. Yes.But since so $c_{|U|}>2^{|U|}$ is an trivial bound.We need something better. 

Comment: Wang, This is a few years old, so better results may be known. The reference I have is: MR1425216 (98d:05145) Alexandr V. Kostochka. *A bound of the cardinality of families not containing $\Delta$-systems*, in **The mathematics of Paul Erdős, II**, 229–235, Algorithms Combin., 14, Springer, Berlin, 1997.

Comment: (Let me know if you need a copy.)

Comment: ＠Andres Thanks, but I think I can get one from library.

Comment: Recent progress on this problem: https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2016/05/17/polymath-10-emergency-post-5-the-erdos-szemeredi-sunflower-conjecture-is-now-proven/